# Can't load external data through D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"> </script>



<body>
<script>

    d3.text("data/cities.csv", function(text) {
        input = d3.csv.parseRows(text).map(function(row) {
            return row.map(function(value) {
                return +value;
            });
        });

    });



</script>
</body>
```

Following is the data I am working on

```
country,city,population,x,y,eu
Austria,Vienna,1826030,386,296,true
Belgium,Brussels,166497,251,240,true
Bulgaria,Sofia,1316557,482,385,true
Croatia,Zagreb,795505,382,337,true
Cyprus,Nicosia,200452,649,499,true
```

Comment: It seems the problem is that you are not doing anything with `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do besides get the csv.

The correct way to do this is:

```
d3.csv('data/cities.csv')
    .row(function(d) { return /* type the data here */ })
    .get(function(error, rows) { console.log(rows); });
```

See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV for more help.